# React Native Linking to open Outlook on Inbox screen?

Tags: react-native, outlook

In React Native I can open the Outlook mail client with this (You also need to add `ms-outlook` to the Info.plist):

```
function openMailClient() {
  Linking.openURL('ms-outlook://');
}
```

This works however if Outlook was already open and looking at an email, then it's opened in the same state ie looking at this email. Instead I would like it to open at the inbox page, as it does when you first open the app.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you need it for? What if the user prefers a different e-mail client?

Comment: @user3840170 in my case this is for an internal company app and we know the users will be using Outlook.

Comment: In your code snippet, I think you're trying to open the browser version. This library could fix the issue maybe : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-email-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, it seems like this is **not possible** at the moment.

I had a similar question, and since I couldn't find any documentation, I decompiled the Outlook apk (version 4.2212.2). I found there are a couple ways to navigate to the inbox if the app is running in the background:

```
'ms-outlook://'
'ms-outlook://emails'
'ms-outlook://emails/inbox'
'ms-outlook://emails/inbox/focused'
'ms-outlook://emails/inbox/other'
```

[This is a gist with some more findings.](https://gist.github.com/Siarl/c3b77938f45b01a33cbb6df1e146a0e7)

When the Outlook app is in the background and you bring it forward with one of these urls, it will navigate to the inbox screen from any page **except** when it is displaying an email. I doubt this is intentional so I think it's best to file a bug report and hope you get a response.